# Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Isoft\Desktop\Apll\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts'

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

Am using windows 10. I created new project called Apll on my ionic, but after i ran ionic serve, it brings out the following errors:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Isoft\Desktop\Apll\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Isoft\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\lib\ionic-angular\app-scripts.js:9:16)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\Isoft\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:107:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (C:\Users\Isoft\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:103:16)
    at Object.importAppScripts (C:\Users\Isoft\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\@ionic\cli-utils\lib\ionic-angular\app-scripts.js:7:20).
```

Do anyone knows how to solve, thanks?

Comment: Reinstall your node modules.

Comment: Run `npm install` in your project directory.

Comment: thanks guy you are a genius, it works.